# How can I avoid the overlap that happens in Framework7 between the navbars when using the material Android theme?

Tags: html-framework-7

I'm using Framework7 to build a hybrid mobile application.

However, I have a problem with the Android version. When I go from the main page to another page by clicking the side menu links I have headers overlapping as you see in the picture. Basically the "App" written in the header of the index.html page overlaps with the "Back" arrow of the about.html page as in the picture below . How can I avoid this?
[first page of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mwka.png)

[image]

The index.html page 
    `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <!-- Your app title -->
    <title></title>
    <!-- Path to Framework7 iOS CSS theme styles-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.ios.min.css">
    <!-- Path to Framework7 iOS related color styles -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.ios.colors.min.css">-->
    <!-- Path to your custom app styles-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.material.colors.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Status bar overlay for full screen mode (PhoneGap) -->
    <div class="statusbar-overlay"></div>
    <!-- Panels overlay-->
    <div class="panel-overlay"></div>
    <!-- Left panel with reveal effect-->
    <div class="panel panel-left panel-reveal">
      <div class="content-block">
        <p>Left panel content goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Views -->
    <div class="views">
      <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class -->
      <div class="view view-main">
        <!-- Top Navbar-->
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <!-- We need cool sliding animation on title element, so we have additional "sliding" class -->
            <div class="center sliding">App</div>
            <div class="right">
              <!-- 
                Right link contains only icon - additional "icon-only" class
                Additional "open-panel" class tells app to open panel when we click on this link
              -->
              <a href="#" class="link icon-only open-panel"><i class="icon icon-bars"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Pages container, because we use fixed-through navbar and toolbar, it has additional appropriate classes-->
        <div class="pages navbar-through toolbar-through">
          <!-- Page, "data-page" contains page name -->
          <div data-page="index" class="page">
            <!-- Scrollable page content -->
            <div class="page-content">
              <p>Page content goes here</p>
              <!-- Link to another page -->
              <a href="about.html">About app</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Bottom Toolbar-->
        <div class="toolbar">
          <div class="toolbar-inner">
            <!-- Toolbar links -->
            <a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Path to Framework7 Library JS-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework7.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Path to your app js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the about.html page

```
 <!-- Top Navbar-->
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="left">
      <a href="#" class="back link">
        <i class="icon icon-back"></i>
        <span>Back</span>
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="center sliding"></div>
    <div class="right">
      <a href="#" class="link icon-only open-panel"><i class="icon icon-bars"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pages">
  <div data-page="about" class="page">
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="content-block">
        <p>Here is About page!</p>
        <p>Fusce eros lectus, accumsan eget mi vel, iaculis tincidunt felis. Nulla tincidunt pharetra sagittis. Fusce in felis eros. Nulla sit amet aliquam lorem, et gravida ipsum. Mauris consectetur nisl non sollicitudin tristique. Praesent vitae metus ac quam rhoncus mattis vel et nisi. Aenean aliquet, felis quis dignissim iaculis, lectus quam tincidunt ligula, et venenatis turpis risus sed lorem. Morbi eu metus elit. Ut vel diam dolor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vladimir mentioned in the same [github question](https://github.com/framework7io/Framework7/issues/595), Use ["Fixed" layout type](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/navbar-toolbar-layouts.html#fixed-layout) for navbars in Material theme and disable `dynamicNavbar`.

**EDIT:**

Looks like there are lots of people complaining about the same issue, maybe for writing the code incorrectly, as the structure of the iOS theme is different than the Material one. So you need to carefully read the [documentation](http://framework7.io/docs/get-started.html) provided in the Framework7 website.

Also, i think you are including the iOS and Material CSS files together in the same page! this is wrong. Anyway, try this:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#2196f3">
    <title>Framework7 Material</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.material.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.material.colors.css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/material-icons.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.png">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="statusbar-overlay"></div>
    <div class="panel-overlay"></div>
    <div class="views">
      <div class="view view-main">
        <div class="pages navbar-fixed">
          <div data-page="index" class="page">
            <div class="navbar">
              <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="center">Framework7</div>
                <div class="right"><a href="#" class="open-panel link icon-only"><i class="icon icon-bars"></i></a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="page-content">
              <div class="content-block-title">Welcome To Framework7</div>
              <div class="list-block">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                  <a href="page2.html" class="item-link">
                      <div class="item-content">
                        <div class="item-media"><i class="icon icon-f7"></i></div>
                        <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="item-title">Click Me</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      </a>
                      </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*my-app.js*

```
// Initialize your app
var myApp = new Framework7({
    material: true
});

// Export selectors engine
var $$ = Dom7;

// Add main View
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
    // Enable dynamic Navbar
    dynamicNavbar: true,
});
```

*page2.html*

```
<div data-page="accordion" class="page">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="left"><a href="index.html" class="back link icon-only"><i class="icon icon-back"></i></a></div>
      <div class="center">Accordion</div>
      <div class="right"><a href="#" class="open-panel link icon-only"><i class="icon icon-bars"></i></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="content-block-title">List View Accordion</div>
    <div class="list-block accordion-list">
      <ul>
        <li class="accordion-item"><a href="#" class="item-link item-content">
            <div class="item-inner"> 
              <div class="item-title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
            </div></a>
          <div class="accordion-item-content">
            <div class="content-block">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean elementum id neque nec commodo. Sed vel justo at turpis laoreet pellentesque quis sed lorem. Integer semper arcu nibh, non mollis arcu tempor vel. Sed pharetra tortor vitae est rhoncus, vel congue dui sollicitudin. Donec eu arcu dignissim felis viverra blandit suscipit eget ipsum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="accordion-item"><a href="#" class="item-link item-content">
            <div class="item-inner"> 
              <div class="item-title">Nested List</div>
            </div></a>
          <div class="accordion-item-content">
            <div class="list-block">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-media"><i class="icon icon-f7"></i></div>
                    <div class="item-inner"> 
                      <div class="item-title">Item 1</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-media"><i class="icon icon-f7"></i></div>
                    <div class="item-inner"> 
                      <div class="item-title">Item 2</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-media"><i class="icon icon-f7"></i></div>
                    <div class="item-inner"> 
                      <div class="item-title">Item 3</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-media"><i class="icon icon-f7"></i></div>
                    <div class="item-inner"> 
                      <div class="item-title">Item 4</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="accordion-item"><a href="#" class="item-link item-content">
            <div class="item-inner"> 
              <div class="item-title">Integer semper</div>
            </div></a>
          <div class="accordion-item-content">
            <div class="content-block">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean elementum id neque nec commodo. Sed vel justo at turpis laoreet pellentesque quis sed lorem. Integer semper arcu nibh, non mollis arcu tempor vel. Sed pharetra tortor vitae est rhoncus, vel congue dui sollicitudin. Donec eu arcu dignissim felis viverra blandit suscipit eget ipsum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content-block-title">Inset Accordion</div>
    <div class="list-block accordion-list inset">
      <ul>
        <li class="accordion-item"><a href="#" class="item-link item-content">
            <div class="item-inner"> 
              <div class="item-title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
            </div></a>
          <div class="accordion-item-content">
            <div class="content-block">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean elementum id neque nec commodo. Sed vel justo at turpis laoreet pellentesque quis sed lorem. Integer semper arcu nibh, non mollis arcu tempor vel. Sed pharetra tortor vitae est rhoncus, vel congue dui sollicitudin. Donec eu arcu dignissim felis viverra blandit suscipit eget ipsum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="accordion-item"><a href="#" class="item-link item-content">
            <div class="item-inner"> 
              <div class="item-title">Nested List</div>
            </div></a>
          <div class="accordion-item-content">
            <div class="list-block">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-media"><i class="icon icon-f7"></i></div>
                    <div class="item-inner"> 
                      <div class="item-title">Item 1</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-media"><i class="icon icon-f7"></i></div>
                    <div class="item-inner"> 
                      <div class="item-title">Item 2</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-media"><i class="icon icon-f7"></i></div>
                    <div class="item-inner"> 
                      <div class="item-title">Item 3</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-media"><i class="icon icon-f7"></i></div>
                    <div class="item-inner"> 
                      <div class="item-title">Item 4</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="accordion-item"><a href="#" class="item-link item-content">
            <div class="item-inner"> 
              <div class="item-title">Integer semper</div>
            </div></a>
          <div class="accordion-item-content">
            <div class="content-block">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean elementum id neque nec commodo. Sed vel justo at turpis laoreet pellentesque quis sed lorem. Integer semper arcu nibh, non mollis arcu tempor vel. Sed pharetra tortor vitae est rhoncus, vel congue dui sollicitudin. Donec eu arcu dignissim felis viverra blandit suscipit eget ipsum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works great now :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice! What do you mean by disable dynamicNavbar ? How can I disable it ?

Comment: It's simple, do that in the app initialization function, [follow this documentation here](https://framework7.io/docs/init-app.html), simply set `dynamicNavbar: false`, read more about Dynamic Navbar [here](https://framework7.io/docs/dynamic-navbar.html).

Comment: I have set the dynamicNavbar: false; and I have a fixed navbar but the problem still persists !!

Comment: Yes, just give me sometime please. For later, do not accept any answer unless you are 100% sure your problem is solved. Will reply to you in a bit :)

Comment: Hi @AlketCecaj, I updated the answer. Copy it and get sure you modify the JS and CSS links, it works as expected.

Comment: Hi @tinyCoder, thank you so much :-) It works properly now!

Comment: Good luck, im happy for you.